# Starting a sentence with "and"-connected adverbs or adverbials

Tags: adverbs, sentence-starts, adverbials

I want compare one thing with two other things, discussing their differences as follows.

> Balls are better than dice, since they provide better rollability.
>   *Moreover and in contrast to eggs*, balls are symmetrical and thereby
>   facilitate rolling equally well in all directions.

Is it valid and commonly used grammar to enumerate adverbs and adverbials with *and*, or should I better put the second adverbial as comma-separated statement: *Moreover, in contrast to eggs* ?

Comment: I'd say "Moreover, in contrast to eggs" is preferable. "Moreover and in contrast to eggs" is pretty clunky. I'd also be happy with "And in contrast to eggs", though.

Comment: @Juve "Moreover, and in contrast to eggs,  ..."  would be my choice.

Comment: I would lose the "moreover" altogether. "Moveover" and "and" together are redundant. "And in contrast to eggs" is best, IMO. Also, when making these kinds of comparisons, the proper preposition is "with," not "to"--"I want compare one thing with two other things, discussing their differences as follows."

Comment: @surlawda The Oxford dictionary cites "in contrast to", but "contrasted with".

Comment: @BillJ I am citing the use of the word "compare," which appears in the first sentence of Juve's query. "Compare with" means to consider the differences and similarities of two things; "compare to" is used when things are alike, without any differences: "Shall I compare thee to a summer's day," "the economy can be compared to a horse charging at the gate," etc. "Contrast" is an entirely different word.

Comment: @surlawda It's usually better to pass quietly over minor errors like that and focus on the example(s) given for analysis.

Comment: @BillJ I had no idea. Why is that?

Comment: @Juve I see two arguments in the second sentence: that balls have the additional (to better rollability) property of being symmetrical and thereby facilitate rolling equally well in all directions, and that that property cannot be ascribed to eggs. The connective adverb “moreover” is semantically stronger than coordinative “and”, and we have to assume that was what the writer intended. I’d leave it as written with just the addition of a comma after “moreover”.

Comment: I guess the question is answered. The "and" is "clunky". PS: @surlawda Thank you for the hint to "compare with".

Comment: (1) Isn't the whole example in need of upgrading? Doesn't 'better rollability' imply 'rolling equally well in all directions'? And this being the case, is 'moreover' (used to add a different point) rather than say 'in fact' (used to refine a point or make it more forceful etc) justifiable? (2) Juxtaposing a contrastive expression with an additive one probably needs more forceful setting off. 'Nitroglycerine is extremely sensitive to heat and physical shocks. Furthermore (and thankfully in contrast to modern high explosives) it degrades over time to even more unstable compounds.'

Comment: (1) I tried to make the example short; maybe too short. Here is an alternative: "Others prefer to roll eggs or dice. However, balls are round and thus roll better than dice. Moreover, and in contrast to eggs, they are symmetrical and roll equally well in all directions". In this case I should in fact use "In fact". (2) However, my original text (not included in the question) more resembles your nitro-example and thus should be wrapped in braces or commas. In this regard, I prefer commas over braces for nicely reading adverbials and use braces only for remarks as seen above in this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, I conclude the following:

Even though "and"-connected adverbs and adverbials might be grammatically correct, the use of a connecting "and" may sound clunky. Most readers will prefer alternative versions of the given statements, e.g., using a single adverbial as in

> And in contrast to eggs, ...

or using a comma-separated, nested phrase as follows.

> Moreover, and in contrast to eggs, ...

Comment: Starting a sentence with coordinating conjunctions is not ungrammatical or undesirable. This is something that was taught long ago and is an archaic "rule". The idea around this teaching was that if you were starting a sentence with such a word there was a good chance you were creating an idea fragment, which is why it was advised against, and for many years people even believed it to be incorrect. ***But*** that is not the case today. ;)